# How do I parse a string in C?

Tags: c

I am a beginner learning C; so, please go easy on me. :)

I am trying to write a very simple program that takes each word of a string into a "Hi (input)!" sentence (it assumes you type in names). Also, I am using arrays because I need to practice them.

My problem is that, some garbage gets putten into the arrays somewhere, and it messes up the program. I tried to figure out the problem but to no avail; so, it is time to ask for expert help. Where have I made mistakes?

p.s.: It also has an infinite loop somewhere, but it is probably the result of the garbage that is put into the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 500 //Maximum Array size.

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int stringArray [MAX];
    int wordArray [MAX];
    int counter = 0;
    int wordCounter = 0;

    printf("Please type in a list of names then hit ENTER:\n");  
    // Fill up the stringArray with user input.
    stringArray[counter] = getchar();
    while (stringArray[counter] != '\n') {
        stringArray[++counter] = getchar();
    }

    // Main function.
    counter = 0;
    while (stringArray[wordCounter] != '\n') {     
        // Puts first word into temporary wordArray.
        while ((stringArray[wordCounter] != ' ') && (stringArray[wordCounter] != '\n')) {
            wordArray[counter++] = stringArray[wordCounter++];
        }
        wordArray[counter] = '\0';

        //Prints out the content of wordArray.
        counter = 0;
        printf("Hi ");
        while (wordArray[counter] != '\0') {
            putchar(wordArray[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
        printf("!\n");

        //Clears temporary wordArray for new use.
        for (counter = 0; counter == MAX; counter++) {
            wordArray[counter] = '\0';
        } 
        wordCounter++;
        counter = 0; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Solved it! I needed to add to following if sentence to the end when I incremented the wordCounter. :)

```
    if (stringArray[wordCounter] != '\n') {
            wordCounter++;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the indention, then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Indentation seems fine to me, don't really know what to edit. :(

Comment: Some kind soul just fixed it for you through an edit. Isn't it nice to be given free fish?

Comment: Step 1: stop thinking of `stdin` as something that is typed in by a user.  The great majority of the time `stdin` is *not* a tty.  `stdin` is a data stream, and the data may come from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for (counter = 0; counter == MAX; counter++) {
        wordArray[counter] = '\0';
    }
```

You never enter into this loop.

Comment: I understand the array size mistake, but I do not understand why it doesn't enter this loop... o.O

Comment: @user1799795 Because for loops work like this: initialize the iterator (counter = 0), then start looping: check the loop condition (counter == MAX), run the loop (code inside {}), then increase the iterator (counter++). In your case, the first check of counter == MAX fails, since counter is 0 and MAX is something else.

Comment: Oh yeah. Such a careless mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are using `int` arrays to represent strings, probably because `getchar()` returns in `int`. However, strings are better represented as `char` arrays, since that's what they are, in C. The fact that `getchar()` returns an `int` is certainly confusing, it's because it needs to be able to return the special value `EOF`, which doesn't fit in a `char`. Therefore it uses `int`, which is a "larger" type (able to represent more different values). So, it can fit all the `char` values, *and* `EOF`.

With `char` arrays, you can use C's string functions directly:

```
char stringArray[MAX];

if(fgets(stringArray, sizeof stringArray, stdin) != NULL)
   printf("You entered %s", stringArray);
```

Note that `fscanf()` will leave the end of line character(s) in the string, so you might want to strip them out. I suggest implementing an in-place function that trims off leading and trailing whitespace, it's a good exercise as well.

Comment: Thanks. You are right about the use of dedicated string functions. However, that would just swipe this problem under the rug. I mean this should work with ints as well, and I need to understand where I made mistakes so I can avoid them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

user1799795,

For what it's worth (now that you've solved your problem) I took the liberty of showing you how I'd do this given the restriction "use arrays", and explaining a bit about why I'd do it that way... Just beware that while I am experienced programmer I'm no C guru... I've worked with guys who absolutely blew me into the C-weeds (pun intended).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 500
#define MAX_WORDS 50
#define WORD_SIZE 20

// Main function.
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int counter = 0;

    // ----------------------------------
    // Read a line of input from the user (ie stdin)
    // ----------------------------------
    char line[LINE_SIZE];
    printf("Please type in a list of names then hit ENTER:\n");
    while ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) == NULL )
        fprintf(stderr, "You must enter something. Pretty please!");

    // A note on that LINE_SIZE parameter to the fgets function:
    // wherever possible it's a good idea to use the version of the standard
    // library function that allows you specificy the maximum length of the
    // string (or indeed any array) because that dramatically reduces the
    // incedence "string overruns", which are a major source of bugs in c
    // programmes.
    // Also note that fgets includes the end-of-line character/sequence in
    // the returned string, so you have to ensure there's room for it in the
    // destination string, and remember to handle it in your string processing.

    // -------------------------
    // split the line into words
    // -------------------------

    // the current word
    char word[WORD_SIZE];
    int wordLength = 0;

    // the list of words
    char words[MAX_WORDS][WORD_SIZE]; // an array of upto 50 words of
                                      // upto 20 characters each
    int wordCount = 0;                // the number of words in the array.


    // The below loop syntax is a bit cyptic.
    // The "char *c=line;" initialises the char-pointer "c" to the start of "line".
    // The " *c;" is ultra-shorthand for: "is the-char-at-c not equal to zero".
    //   All strings in c end with a "null terminator" character, which has the
    //   integer value of zero, and is commonly expressed as '\0', 0, or NULL
    //   (a #defined macro). In the C language any integer may be evaluated as a
    //   boolean (true|false) expression, where 0 is false, and (pretty obviously)
    //   everything-else is true. So: If the character at the address-c is not
    //   zero (the null terminator) then go-round the loop again. Capiche?
    // The "++c" moves the char-pointer to the next character in the line. I use
    // the pre-increment "++c" in preference to the more common post-increment
    // "c++" because it's a smidge more efficient.
    //
    // Note that this syntax is commonly used by "low level programmers" to loop
    // through strings. There is an alternative which is less cryptic and is
    // therefore preferred by most programmers, even though it's not quite as
    // efficient. In this case the loop would be:
    //    int lineLength = strlen(line);
    //    for ( int i=0; i<lineLength; ++i)
    // and then to get the current character
    //        char ch = line[i];
    // We get the length of the line once, because the strlen function has to
    // loop through the characters in the array looking for the null-terminator
    // character at its end (guess what it's implementation looks like ;-)...
    // which is inherently an "expensive" operation (totally dependant on the
    // length of the string) so we atleast avoid repeating this operation.
    //
    // I know I might sound like I'm banging on about not-very-much but once you
    // start dealing with "real word" magnitude datasets then such habits,
    // formed early on, pay huge dividends in the ability to write performant
    // code the first time round. Premature optimisation is evil, but my code
    // doesn't hardly ever NEED optimising, because it was "fairly efficient"
    // to start with. Yeah?

    for ( char *c=line; *c; ++c ) {    // foreach char in line.

        char ch = *c;  // "ch" is the character value-at the-char-pointer "c".

        if ( ch==' '               // if this char is a space,
          || ch=='\n'              // or we've reached the EOL char
        ) {
            // 1. add the word to the end of the words list.
            //    note that we copy only wordLength characters, instead of
            //    relying on a null-terminator (which doesn't exist), as we
            //    would do if we called the more usual strcpy function instead.
            strncpy(words[wordCount++], word, wordLength);
            // 2. and "clear" the word buffer.
            wordLength=0;
        } else if (wordLength==WORD_SIZE-1) { // this word is too long
            // so split this word into two words.
            strncpy(words[wordCount++], word, wordLength);
            wordLength=0;
            word[wordLength++] = ch;
        } else {
            // otherwise: append this character to the end of the word.
            word[wordLength++] = ch;
        }
    }

    // -------------------------
    // print out the words
    // -------------------------

    for ( int w=0; w<wordCount; ++w ) {
        printf("Hi %s!\n", words[w]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the real world one can't make such restrictive assumptions about the maximum-length of words, or how many there will be, and if such restrictions are given they're almost allways arbitrary and therefore proven wrong all too soon... so straight-off-the-bat for this problem, I'd be inclined to use a linked-list instead of the "words" array... wait till you get to "dynamic data structures"... You'll love em ;-)

Cheers. Keith.

PS: You're going pretty well... My advise is "just keep on truckin"... this gets a LOT easier with practice.